# apache .htaccess set subfolder to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to create `admin.example.com`, The URL router I am using is `www.example.com/admin`, I do not want to share the same login session. So I am thinking to use subdomain to solve this issue.

the admin actually is not a folder, it is a route from my route file. I am using Laravel 5.1.

What I want is when user access
`http://admin.example.com`, it actually pointing to `http://www.example.com/admin`. However, user browser still showing `http://admin.example.com`

Any idea how do I able to in .htaccess?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

#Below is the code I added for the admin subdomain which doing a redirect, but I would like a mapping, not redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/admin/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
#end of subdomain

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Above code what it does is redirect, but what I want to a mapping.

vhost config file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.example.com
        DocumentRoot "C:\Bitnami\www\example.com\public"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName admin.example.com
        DocumentRoot "C:\Bitnami\www\example.com\public"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with a .htaccess. You have to configure the VirtualHost directly in the Apache config.

You can combine your two VirtualHosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias admin.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:\Bitnami\www\example.com\public"
</VirtualHost>
```

Then you have to adapt your routing in Laravel. But this turns the question in a programming question, making it off topic for this site. I found some examples in a quick google search for `laravel multiple domains`, I suggest you do the same.

Comment: I had added the virtualhost on the subdomain, I had updated my question, the /admin actually is not a folder, it is a routing from a controller.

Comment: Please add the virtualhost configuration to your question

Comment: both is the set to the same folder, I had added

Comment: I am not looking for multiple domain, I actually want ppl access admin.example.com is pointing to www.example.com/admin, maybe the question is proxy?

Comment: Having two domains (normal and subdomain) IS multiple domains. Of course you can proxy apache to itself, you can also force redirects for all example.com/admin requests to admin.example.com, but both ways don't make much sense. The proper way to do this is to adapt the routing.

Comment: can you share the solution how to  proxy it? I haven't do anything with apache proxy before. the idea to have separated sub domain to avoid share cookie session.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for a Reverse Proxy. Normally the easiest is to configure that from the VirtualHost entry:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName admin.example.com
        ProxyPass / http://www.example.com/admin/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://www.example.com/admin/
</VirtualHost>
```

But the [`ProxyPass`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)  directive is also valid in a `.htaccess` context.

Comment: It works for the homepage. When I access to admin.example.com, it redirect to admin.example.com/login. However, when I post the form, it keep redirect back the admin.example.com/login, When I view the source it is still showing http://www.example.com/admin/login/

I also tried added in routes.php below code:-

\URL::forceRootUrl('http://admin.example.com/');

When I view the source it is showing `http://admin.example.com/admin/login/` which is not correct, it should be `http://admin.example.com/login/`